# How can I re-run Vue.js ApolloClient middleware?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, apollo, vue-apollo

In my `main.js` I have some code that checks for the existence of a localStorage item. If it has it, it will add an `Authorization` header via middleware to the ApolloClient setup.

However, if a localStorage item is *later added*, it's not present in the middleware of `main.js`. A *full page refresh* is therefore required in order to get it to pick it up / know of its existence.

How can I run `main.js` again (if that's even the solution) from a method in say, a component that signs the user in?

Here's my `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({ uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/MY-ID-HERE' })
const requestToken = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN')

networkInterface.use([{
  applyMiddleware (req, next) {
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {}
    }
    req.options.headers['Authorization'] = requestToken ? `Bearer ${requestToken}` : null
    next()
  }
}])

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface
})

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: apolloClient
})

Vue.use(VueApollo)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App />',
  components: {
    App
  },
  apolloProvider,
  router,
  store
})
```

Hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to move your `requestToken` declaration inside the `applyMiddleware` function. This way, you'll check local storage for a token every time a request is made. Otherwise, it's only checked once, when the page is loaded and you end up seeing the behavior you described.

```
networkInterface.use([{   applyMiddleware (req, next) {
    const requestToken = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN')
    if (!req.options.headers) {
      req.options.headers = {}
    }
    req.options.headers['Authorization'] = requestToken ? `Bearer ${requestToken}` : null
    next()   } }])
```

Comment: Oh my lord. It was really that easy? I think I've been staring at the screen for too long today. Thanks for your help. It did the trick!